# The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported in c sharp

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-collation

I am currently using C sharp .net 6 and connecting to a database using System.Data.SqlClient.

When it attempts to read from a table, it returns the error: The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported.

```
        private const string SQLUSERS= @"SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY ID COLLATE German_PhoneBook_CI_AI;";

        SqlConnection connection = new("...");
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            using SqlCommand command = new(SQLUSERS, connection);
            using SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();


            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                ...
            }
```

The current server collation is German_PhoneBook_CI_AI and it is not possible for me to change it. Any alternatives to resolve this issue with the code and without using EF Core?

Comment: When I read this, it seems to be purely a SQL Server issue, nothing to do with System.Data.SqlClient or C#. If you run the same sql in SSMS you will see the same error ?

Comment: @bbsimonbb no on SSMS it runs fine.

Comment: Look into https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with .net 6, [fixed in December 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/62155). I think your only hope is to make sure you're on the latest .net 6 version [(6.0.16)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET).